# Derivative of $e^{e^{e^x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\Large e^{e^{e^x}}$$ Derivative of this function needs to be found out but I am not getting any substitution. Any help/hint would do . Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I perfectly dont know the LaTeX.

Comment: Apply the chain rule repeatedly: what for instance is the derivative of $e^{e^x}$?

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Think of the function as $e^{f(x)}$, where $f(x)=e^{e^x}$.

Step 2: Apply the chain rule.  At some point you will need $f'(x)$, which will need the chain rule again.

Comment: Another look at it, take $g(x) = e^x$, then $f(x)=g(g(g(x))) = e^{e^{e^x}}$